# Meaning of "We got this"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

In a hostage situation, a police officer says

> We don't need the FBI here. We got this.

What does "We got this" mean? Could it mean "We got this thing under control"?

Comment: It's slangy / colloquial: *We **have** got **control of** this [situation].*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you got it right, though I'd say "we *have* this thing under control".

The verb 'to get' is very flexible, I'm struggling to find an equivalent definition for this in a [dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/get). But this usage is fairly common.